# Search JSON array and return sibling tag value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON array defined like this:

```
var neighbourhood = [
    {"result": "A good one", "streetname": ["First Street", "Second Street"]},
    {"result": "A bad one", "streetname": ["Lorem Street", "Ipsum Street"]},
    {"result": "Undecided", "streetname": ["Ketchup Street"]}
    ];
```

I'm trying to make a web app that would have you input the street name and output the result. For example, if you input "Lorem Street", I'd need "A bad one" returned.

I'm explicitly avoiding SQL and PHP, so how would I go about doing that in Javascript with a JSON array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to a 'normal' loop, you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
function getResult(name) {
  var result = neighbourhood.filter(function (el) {
    return el.streetname.indexOf(name) > -1;
  });
  return result.length > 0 ? result[0].result : false;
}

getResult('Lorem Street'); // A bad one
```

Edit: It returns false if no match is found.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShmnJ/13/)

Comment: Good, but now a street that's not found throws an error: `TypeError: neighbourhood.filter(...)[0] is undefined`: http://jsfiddle.net/ShmnJ/8/

Comment: Follow-up question: If, say, there are two Lorem Street streets and they are in different "categories", is there any way to return both? Ex. "A good one or Undecided"

Comment: Instead of returning `result[0].result` just return `result`, and then loop over the returned array: http://jsfiddle.net/ShmnJ/18/

Answer (score 1):

```
var neighbourhood = [
    {"result": "A good one", "streetname": ["First Street", "Second Street"]},
    {"result": "A bad one", "streetname": ["Lorem Street", "Ipsum Street"]},
    {"result": "Undecided", "streetname": ["Ketchup Street"]}
];

function getStreetResult(street) {
    for(var i = 0; i < neighbourhood.length; i++) {
        if(neighbourhood[i].streetname.indexOf(street) >= 0) {
            return neighbourhood[i].result;
        } 
    }
}

alert(getStreetResult('Lorem Street'));
```

Comment: Huh, returns undefined.

Comment: @user3244833, it will return `undefined` if nothing is found. But running the code above alerts `A bad one`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one please. Many thanks

```
 <script>
            var neighbourhood = [
                {"result": "A good one", "streetname": ["First Street", "Second Street"]},
                {"result": "A bad one", "streetname": ["Lorem Street", "Ipsum Street"]},
                {"result": "Undecided", "streetname": ["Ketchup Street"]}
            ];
            function submit(){
                var str = document.getElementById('txt').value;
                neighbourhood.forEach(function(neighbour){
                    neighbour.streetname.forEach(function(street){
                        if (str==street)
                        {
                            alert(neighbour.result);
                            return;
                        }

                    })
                })
            }

        </script>


    <input type="text" id="txt">
    <br>
    <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```